# Finding the percent of times a word occurance of a Nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a little new to SQL but I am trying to figure out how to find the percent of times certain words occurs in a Nvarchar column.

The column titled `Location`has 6 possible values:

- Home
- Home Health
- SNF
- Acute
- Other
- Unknown

I want to know in the percent of times `Home` and `Home Health` appear.

My query looks something like this.

```
Select 
    Year,
    (Select Count (Location Where Location = 'Home' or 'Home Health")/Count(Location))
From Database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to select per Year how many times Home & Home Heath is in de database

```
select Year, Location, count(*)
From Database where Location in ('Home', 'Home Health')
group by Year, location
```

And this to calculate percentage

```
select Year, Location, CAST(count(*) as decimal) * 100 / (select count(*) from Location)
From Database where Location in ('Home', 'Home Health')
group by Year, location
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following query you should get the percentage rounded for each Year and Location respect to the whole number of elements in your table:

```
SELECT Year, Location,
 round( count(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM Database) , 1)
 FROM Database
 GROUP BY Year, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Below, you'll see a sample table with sample data. I then declare variables to capture the number of rows and number of times we encouter your matching words.  Lastly, I added the NULLIF syntax to prevent a divide-by-zero error if there are no records in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE ##test1
(location VARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO ##test1
    VALUES  ('home'), ('office'),('work'),('home office'),('apartment'),('home health')

    DECLARE @instancecount DECIMAL (12,4) = (SELECT COUNT(location) FROM ##test1 where Location in ('Home', 'Home Health'))
    DECLARE @totalcount DECIMAL (12,4) = (SELECT COUNT(location) FROM ##test1)

SELECT  (@instancecount/NULLIF(@totalcount,0))

DROP TABLE ##test1
```